# Remove an item from the drop down menu

Tags: javascript, canvas, popup

I want to remove BOX from the list:
[image: I want to remove BOX from the list]

In my .js file I use:

```
$('#context_external_tools_select li:contains("BOX")').remove();
```

It works in the console but it does not work after I upload the JavaScript to the server. By the way, it is Canvas LMS.

Comment: please click "
I want to remove BOX from the list" to see the screenshot .

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#context_external_tools_select li:contains("BOX")').remove();
});
```

Most likely the reason this works in the console is you're executing the code after the DOM has fully loaded.  If this doesn't work with document.ready, you need to check your console for errors.

Comment: Hi Chris, I already insert the line inside the document.ready. In LMS, I can change the element behind the pop up window. But I have a hard time to modify elements on this window.